# Section duplicates whenever I add a specific Field

Tags: crystal-reports

I added a primary key field into my report. In doing so, the Details section automatically duplicates. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you post your design and your schema?

Comment: Hi thanks heringer, my laptop is offline atm. Im gonna upload the screenshot of it about 7 hours from now